# Which XGBoost loss function should I use if I want to maximize the correlation between prediction and true value?

Tags: xgboost, loss-function

Which XGBoost loss function should I use if I want to maximize the correlation between prediction and true value? Or should I custom a new loss function?

Comment: What kind of correlation do you have in mind? At the moment the question it too broad, as **ALL** loss functions aim on maximizing correlation between prediction and truth just defining what is important in different ways.

Comment: mainly two: 1.Spearman's rank correlation coefficient.2.Pearson correlation coefficient

Comment: Why don't you just try several losses that you have at your disposal (`mae`, `mse` for regression and logloss for classification)? Then just check wich one gives you better correlation on the training and validation samples. I think, the conclusion on the optimal loss choice will depend on your problem and your data